# AlertmanagerConfig CRD configuration to allow email sending

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus-alertmanager, prometheus-operator

We have setup Prometheus in a kubernetes cluster using PrometheusOperator. We are trying to configure AlertManager using the AlertManagerConfig custom resource. We tried to configure a Sendgrid account to make Alertmanager able to send e-mail alert notifications.

Sharing the test config below (filename: monitoring-alertmanager-configmap.yaml):

```
apiVersion: monitoring.coreos.com/v1alpha1
kind: AlertmanagerConfig
metadata:
  name: example
  spec:
    receivers:
    - name: 'email'
      email_configs:
      - to: 'my@email.com'
        from: 'alertmanager@email.com'
        smarthost: smtp.sendgrid.net:587
        auth_username: 'apikey'
        auth_password: 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
  route:
    group_by: ['alertname']
    group_wait: 10s
    group_interval: 10s
    repeat_interval: 10s
    receiver: 'email'
```

Now, when I try to apply it, I got this error:

$ kubectl apply -f monitoring-alertmanager-configmap.yaml

error: error validating "monitoring-alertmanager-configmap.yaml": error validating data: [ValidationError(AlertmanagerConfig.metadata): unknown field "route" in io.k8s.apimachinery.pkg.apis.meta.v1.ObjectMeta, ValidationError(AlertmanagerConfig.metadata): unknown field "spec" in io.k8s.apimachinery.pkg.apis.meta.v1.ObjectMeta, ValidationError(AlertmanagerConfig): missing required field "spec" in com.coreos.monitoring.v1alpha1.AlertmanagerConfig]; if you choose to ignore these errors, turn validation off with --validate=false

Someone could guide me in this?

Comment: Maybe @aaruja could take a look?

Comment: spec should not be in metadata, and route should be in spec

Answer (score 0):

Alignment is wrong. You have to move the next block 2 spaces to the left.

```
  spec:
    receivers:
    - name: 'email'
      email_configs:
      - to: 'my@email.com'
        from: 'alertmanager@email.com'
        smarthost: smtp.sendgrid.net:587
        auth_username: 'apikey'
        auth_password: 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
```